# Constructor is not defined, but it is?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a game for a project in  university (freshman year), that runs in console, in a language that I am kind of self taught in since it's the one I know the best, but I'm running into a lot of problems, since I'm very new, so sorry if the question is obvious/bad.

Basically how it is supposed to work is a player will get a choice to choose a school of magic and then three spells from that school (type) of magic will be added, and the player needs to choose 3 schools which will then be assigned to their 1-9 keys. The game is turn based and I thought it out in advance, but when I try to create the Spell objects I get the error `The constructor Spell (String, int, int, String, String, String) is undefined` and `the value of (insert whatever spell name here) is not used.`. Now the second is true, but it shouldn't make the program unrunnable, since it will be used later, but I don't get why the first one is showing up when I made that constructor, sorry if the question is a bit messy again, here's the code.

```
public class Spell {
int damage;
int absorb;
String type;
String priority;
String name;


public Spell(String name, int damage, int absorb, String type, String priority, String direction){
    System.out.println("\nYou learned: " + this.name);
}
}
```

And the player class is :

```
public class Player {
int hp = 100;
String type1,type2,type3;

public void Types() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);          //lets both players choose their three spell types
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Choose your first element : \n 1.Frost\t\t2.Lighting\t\t3.Earth\n 4.Fire\t\t5.Water\t\t6.Wood\n 7.Wind\t\t8.Runes\t\t9.Chaos ");
    while (i > 3){
        if (i == 1 || i == 2){
            System.out.println("Choose your next element : \n 1.Frost\t\t2.Lighting\t\t3.Earth\n 4.Fire\t\t5.Water\t\t6.Wood\n 7.Wind\t\t8.Runes\t\t9.Chaos ");
        }
        int pick = scan.nextInt();                  //i increases every time the player picks a type, type is stored to the position and will be assigned
                                                    // controls based on what position the type is in (type1 - 1,2,3; type 2 - 4,5,6 etc)
        if (pick == 1){                             // for every CHOOSEN type it creates three objects from the spell class
            Spell frostBolt = new Spell("Frost bolt", 20, 0, "Frost", "Attack", "Projectile");
            Spell coneOfCold = new Spell ("Cone of Cold", 5, 0, "Frost", "Defense", "Cone");
            Spell icedEarth = new Spell("Iced Earth", 0, 0, "Frost", "Field", "Ground");

            if (i == 0){
                type1 = "frost";
            }
            else if (i == 1){
                type2 = "forst";
            }
            else{
                type3 = "frost";
            }
            i++;
        }
        else if (pick == 2){
            Spell thunder = new Spell("Thunder", 15, 0, "Lightning", "Attack", "Overhead");
            Spell staticField = new Spell ("Static Field", 5, 0, "Lightning", "Field", "Air");
            Spell absortionBlast = new Spell("Absortion Blast", 0, 100, "Lightning", "Defense", "Self");

            if (i == 0){
                type1 = "lightning";
            }
            else if (i == 1){
                type2 = "lightning";
            }
            else{
                type3 = "lightning";
            }
            i++;
        }
```

etc.

Is there something OOP related that I'm doing wrong, I really can't figure it out, been bashing my head against it for a few hours already, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have `Spell extends Player` ? Do you think that a spell is a kind of player?

Comment: Oh, that was left from when I was just trying random stuff to make it work after trying to figure it out , but that shouldn't be left there, I will edit it out, thank you.

Comment: It'd be nice to see the actual compiler error because it appears it's the `Player` class from which `Spell` inherits from is the problem.  For some reason your have defined a `Types()` constructor in `Player` and not a `Player` constructor.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I just get `null` value of name, but that's not the problem. Could you show the project structure?

Comment: @gonczor I managed to "figure it out", I wrote what the problem was in the edit, thank you very much for looking into helping me out, I appreciate it very much,

Comment: Hi @Ace. I see you deleted your answer, you added as an edit. But now you leave an unanswered question, which is not relevant to SO, as it was an oversight on your end. You should create a delete vote, so it can be removed.